# Azure AD timeout after 20-30 mins idle - how to avoid it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET MVC5-application, using Azure AD to let Office365 users from different organizations authenticate.

However, if the web application is idle for about 20 minutes, the user is redirected to the login page at the next click/reload. Problem is that the user won't notice this right away, because they are not redirected due to updates on the page are async JS-based...which is then not saved to the database. But when the page is refreshed, they are then redirected to the login.

How do I avoid that login timeout after idle for 20 minutes? I don't really want them to be logged out at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the encryption/decryption key for the authentication cookie is being generated on application startup. When the application gets shut down from being idle, the next startup the application can't decrypt previously issued authentication cookies essentially logging everyone out.

You'll need to set the [`<machineKey />` element in the web.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of your application. You can use a service online to generate it or IIS has a built in machine key generator if you don't trust the online services.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the application would shut down. I mean, I can understand the session expires, but why would the application shut down just because one user is not using the application for some time?

Comment: @Anders By default, IIS will terminate an application after it has been idle for 20 minutes. That setting can be changed in the IIS Management Console under the Application Pool. If you're using Azure Web App/Web Sites, then you may want to look into AlwaysOn functionality which can deliver similar functionality.

Comment: I already had "Always On" turned on, and it doesn't seem to make any difference on the described problem.